# Calculate avrage of mysql result php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I want to calculate the avrage of a mysql result in PHP (I'm using CodeIgniter as framework).
My (model) code:

```
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT stars FROM feedback');
    $res = $query->result_array();
    $avrage = array_sum($res); // The impossible part
    $avrage = round($avrage,0);
```

The result of the query looks like this: (print_r) `Array ( [0] => Array ( [stars] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [stars] => 3 ) )`

I just want the '5' and '3' in a separate array, so array_sum() can do it's job. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in SQL directly using [AVG()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)

```
SELECT avg(stars) as avg_stars
FROM feedback
```

Comment: Not can but should, as it´s going to be much faster ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `AVG` directly in your query?

```
'SELECT AVG(stars) as average FROM feedback'
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to modify your SQL query, like this: `SELECT AVG(stars) as stars_average FROM feedback`. Then, after fetching the result set, you can do the following in your PHP code: `$average = $res[0]['stars_average'];`.